# Error: "friends.find is not a function" when using live server but not with localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

Description:
Whenever I switch from using localhost as my API endpoint to my actual backend live URL, I encounter two errors in my React application. Here are the errors I'm facing:

```
PATCH https://hobby-hunter-api.onrender.com/users/6488a0ab682e930dcd661111/64628638beaa4cc4aecd3a42 404 (Not Found) in Friend.jsx:25

`Uncaught TypeError: friends.find is not a function in Friend.jsx:22
```

I am using MongoDB and Node.js for the backend.
appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Additional details:
Please let me know if there's any additional information or code snippets needed to help diagnose the problem.

Friend component code:

```
    import { PersonAddOutlined, PersonRemoveOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Box, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { setFriends } from "state";

import UserImage from "./UserImage";

const Friend = ({ friendId, name, userPicturePath }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { _id } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
  const friends = useSelector((state) => state.user.friends);

  const isFriend = friends && friends.find((friend) => friend._id === friendId); // Check if the friend exists

  const patchFriend = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://weblinkbackendapi.onrender.com/users/${_id}/${friendId}`,
      {
        method: "PATCH",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch(setFriends({ friends: data }));
  };

  if (!Array.isArray(friends)) {
    return null; // Return null if friends is not an array
  }

  return (
    <Box className="text-black flex mb-2 bg-zinc-200 justify-between items-center rounded-lg z-10 ease-in duration-500">
      <Box className="flex justify-between items-center gap-1">
        <UserImage image={userPicturePath} />
        <Box
          onClick={() => {
            navigate(`/profile/${friendId}`);
            navigate(0);
          }}
        >
          <h2 className="text-black font-medium hover:text-white cursor-pointer p-2 mr-1">
            {name}
          </h2>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <IconButton
        onClick={() => patchFriend()}
        sx={{ p: "0.05rem", fontSize: "0.25rem" }}
      >
        {isFriend ? (
          <PersonRemoveOutlined sx={{ color: "grey" }} />
        ) : (
          <PersonAddOutlined sx={{ color: "grey" }} />
        )}
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Friend;
```

Comment: Something other than an array is getting into state.user.friends. So when you try to call friends.find() the function doesn't exist and you get the error, i would put a console.log(friends) before this line to see what is been passed there

Comment: Please [edit] to include your redux code so we can see what the state is and how it's updated. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a conditional render for the patch a friend function for the current user.The problem was happening when the current user requested himself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There're some problems with your code:

1. Your TypeError occurred because `friends` was not an array as expected. The friends array check must be proceeded before any further actions, so move it up:

```js
if (!Array.isArray(friends)) {
    return null; // Return null if friends is not an array
}

const isFriend = friends.find((friend) => friend._id === friendId); // Check if the friend exists
...
```

2. Your PATCH request failed, you need to check if the API is working and handle error in your code. Reading your logic, your fetching request method should be `GET`, not `PATCH`.
3. By any chance, can `state.user.friends` a single person? If so, you need to handle the case.